# When implies a linear relation in the function parameters also a linear relation in the derivatives?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a function $f(x,y)$ of two variables $x$ and $y$.

The variables $x$ and $y$ on which $f$ depends occur only in the form $a(x-by)$ with the constants $a$ and $b$. (For additional clarification: $f(x,y)=12+(a(x-by))^5$ or $f(x,y)=(a(x-by))^{1/2}-8(a(x-by))$ would qualify, $f(x,y)=xy$ would not)

So, we may write

$$f(x,y)=g(z)$$

with $z=a(x-by)$.

Now, build the ratio of the derivatives $\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{\partial x} \partial f(x,y)}{\dfrac{1}{\partial y} \partial f(x,y)}$ which is sometimes $-1/b$, sometimes it is not that trivial.

For example, if $g(z)=\sqrt z=\sqrt{a(x-by)}$ it works, also for certain polynomials (see above), but not for all.

Does anybody know a general rule describing this issue?

Comment: My first idea would be that a(x-by) must only "occur for one time", but this is far away from a proper mathematical explanation

Comment: I don't understand your second and third sentences. For instance let $f(x,y) = xy$ and suppose $g(a(x-by)) = f(x,y) = xy$ for all $x$ and $y$. Then $g(ax) = g(a(x-b\cdot 0)) = x\cdot 0 = 0$ for all $x$, implying that $g$ is the zero function or that $a=0$, both of which are absurd.

Comment: I hope it is clear now

Comment: Perfectly clear. So you only consider $f$ such that $f(x,y) = g(ax-aby)$ for some $g$? For this class of functions your ratio of derivatives should equal $-\frac{1}{b}$ though (at least whenever it's defined). What counterexample have you encountered?

Comment: Yes, exactly. 
Consider for instance $f(x,y) = (a (y - b x)) - (a (y - b x))^4$. The ratio would be $(a - 4 a^4 (-b x + y)^3)/(-a b + 4 a^4 b (-b x + y)^3)$

Comment: Which equals $-\frac{1}{b}$ wherever it's defined, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed. Thx. Would you go that far to say that there is a general rule in the way: $-b \partial f(a(x-b y))/\partial x=  \partial f(a(x-b y))/\partial y$ if both partial derivatives exist at a given $x$ and $y$

Comment: It's a straightforward consequence of the chain rule: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(ax-aby) = f^\prime(ax-aby)\cdot a$, whereas $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(ax-aby) = f^\prime(ax-aby)\cdot(-ab)$.

Comment: Beautiful. Thx a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. And a lot less complicated than I expected :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Abel in comments: If $f(x,y)=g(x-by)$ then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)=g'(x-by)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)=-bg'(x-by)$, hence the relation 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y)=-b\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,y)$$
holds.

Alternative, geometric explanation: the function $f$ is constant  on every line of the form $x=by+C$, and the gradient of $f$ is always orthogonal to level curves of $f$.